# Rothschild-Stiglitz working paper?

Tags: reference-request, adverse-selection

I recently rediscovered Rothschild and Stiglitz's classic paper, ["Equilibrium in Competitive Insurance Markets"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1885326).

In footnote 7, they refer to an earlier version of their paper for details on the robustness of their results to their assumptions. Does anyone know how to track that version down? Many different Google search queries haven't worked.

The complete citation for the working paper is

> Rothschild, M., and J. E. Stiglitz, "Equilibrium in Competitive Insurance Markets," Technical Report No. 170, IMSSS Stanford University, 1975.

On a separate note, the published version of their paper is beautifully written. You would be remiss to not have read it.

Comment: IMSSS stands for Institute for Mathematical Studies in the Social Sciences, which has been superseded by the [Stanford Institute for Theoretical Economics (SITE)](https://site.stanford.edu/). You could try [contacting them](http://web.stanford.edu/group/SITE/contact_us.htm) to see if they have archived technical reports from the IMSSS era. Their website suggests that they have papers going back to [at least 1990](http://web.stanford.edu/group/SITE/tech_reports.html). BTW, your link to the paper seems wrong.

Comment: @HerrK. Thanks, I've fixed the link. I did figure out that IMSSS was the predecessor to SITE from my Google searches, but I was hoping someone here might know an easier way than trying to contact them directly first. I'll try that too in a couple of days.

Comment: You can also contact the authors directly. They may have it digitized, they may even go into the trouble of digitizing it now, or they may direct you to some other paper where sensitivity/robustness analysis of their results is conducted.

Comment: It is a bit unfortunate that the older versions of several papers are not available anymore on web because of the renaming of institutions etc. I rememember I also wanted to an older version of a paper that the auhors had referred to in their published version. I could not find and when I wrote to the author(s) they replied saying unfortunately they had lost it too. Incidently, the paper was in the literauture related to R-S (1976) paper. Good luck. It would be a service to the community if you could post the paper if you do get it eventually. Also, I agree this paper is beautifully written.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Edited)
Here is the working paper. Enjoy.

Rothschild, M., and J. E. Stiglitz, "Equilibrium in Competitive Insurance Markets," Technical Report No. 170, IMSSS Stanford University, 1975.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MXb3OcOQc_lxNYC4CzsNTTax9_3Q_4UN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Interesting. Why wouldn't that be appropriate? It would be great to make it public.

Comment: Maybe you're right. I uploaded it.

Comment: Could you edit your post so that it is clearer how it answers the quesiton?

Comment: @Ubiquitous you mean like this? Including the complete title? I am new here, so might be missing some generally-accepted practices.

Comment: Yes, looks good thank you. The general principle here is that answers are not only for the original poster, but should also be a reference resource for those who come later (like a mini Wikipedia). So we like to aim for some level of polish in the answers. Thanks for helping out!